# Add livedoc-mocha to existing project

Tags: javascript, npm, mocha.js

I'm trying add livedoc-mocha (https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/LiveDoc/tree/master/packages/livedoc-mocha) to an existing project here: https://github.com/rocket-pool/rocketpool

I installed livedoc with `npm install --save-dev livedoc-mocha` but as for this part I'm not sure what to do

```
mocha --ui livedoc-mocha --reporter livedoc-mocha/livedoc-spec --recursive path-to-my-tests/
```

Is there a way to modify an existing configuration file within this repo so that when I run `npm test` it will run mocha with livedoc-mocha? This is what the test field in the scripts section looks like in package.json:

```
"test": "hardhat test test/rocket-pool-tests.js",
```

There is also a hardhat.config.js file which has a mocha section that looks like this:

```
mocha: {
    timeout: 0,
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to integrate `livedoc-mocha` with the existing project and have it work when you run `npm test`, you can modify the `hardhat.config.js` and the `package.json` files.

- [`hardhat.config.js`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config): This file already has a mocha section, so you can specify the UI and reporter there (same options as in a regular [`.mocharc.js`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js)).

  ```js
  // hardhat.config.js
  module.exports = {
      // ... other configurations
      mocha: {
          timeout: 0,
          ui: 'livedoc-mocha',
          reporter: 'livedoc-mocha/livedoc-spec',
          recursive: true
      },
      // ... other configurations
  };
  ```

  This tells Hardhat to use `livedoc-mocha` as the UI and reporter for Mocha, and to recursively search for test files.
- `package.json`: You should modify the `test` script in the `scripts` section of the `package.json` file to point to the tests you want to run with `livedoc-mocha`. Since you are using Hardhat, you can continue to use the `hardhat test` command, and it will pick up the Mocha configuration from the `hardhat.config.js` file. If you want to specify a particular test file or directory, you can do so in the `hardhat test` command:

  ```json
  // package.json
  {
      "scripts": {
          "test": "hardhat test path-to-my-tests/"
      }
      // ... other scripts and configurations
  }
  ```

  Replace `path-to-my-tests/` with the path to the directory or file containing your tests.

After making these changes, when you run `npm test`, it should use Mocha with `livedoc-mocha` as specified in the `hardhat.config.js` file.

---

> I am getting the following error.
>
> ```
> hardhat test test/deposit/deposit-pool-tests-bdd.js  
> An unexpected error occurred:  
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detailLevel')
> ```

It appears the issue is due to the way [`livedoc-mocha`](https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/LiveDoc/tree/master/packages/livedoc-mocha) interacts with [`hardhat`](https://hardhat.org/).

The `livedoc-mocha` is a reporter that changes the display of the test results. It is possible `hardhat` does not fully support the options `livedoc-mocha` provides.
`hardhat` only supports a specific set of reporters, none of which are `livedoc-mocha`. So, if you want to use `livedoc-mocha` with your tests, you may have to run your tests directly with `mocha` instead of through `hardhat`.

If you want to proceed with this route, you can change the `test` script in your `package.json` to use `mocha` instead of `hardhat` as follows:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --ui livedoc-mocha --reporter livedoc-mocha/livedoc-spec --recursive test/",
  },
}
```

Note: If you have globally installed `mocha`, you can use the `mocha` command directly. Otherwise, you will need to use the `mocha` binary from your local `node_modules` directory: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha`.

However, be aware that by switching to `mocha`, you will lose `hardhat`'s specific features. If you rely on those features for your tests, you will need to find a way to integrate `mocha` with `hardhat` or find a compatible reporter that provides the same functionality as `livedoc-mocha`.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestions but am getting the following error.  `> hardhat test test/deposit/deposit-pool-tests-bdd.js

An unexpected error occurred:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'detailLevel')` and then it complains about LiveDocSpec.setOptions, LiveDocReporter, Mocha.run,

Comment: I removed the reporter line from the mocha configuration and got it to work

Comment: @user2007843 That means `hardhat` only supports a specific set of reporters, none of which are `livedoc-mocha`. So, if you want to use `livedoc-mocha` with your tests, you may have to run your tests directly with `mocha` instead of through `hardhat`. You can change the `test` script in your `package.json` to use `mocha` instead of `hardhat` , with `"test": "mocha --ui livedoc-mocha --reporter livedoc-mocha/livedoc-spec --recursive test/",`

Comment: @user2007843 I would edit the answer to put more details... but [I cannot edit my own answers at the moment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message).

Comment: @user2007843 I have edited the answer to address your comment / error message.