# Convert existing mocha tests to livedoc mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity, bdd, hardhat

I've been able to integrate livedoc-mocha into an existing repo from the steps here: [Add livedoc-mocha to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542406/add-livedoc-mocha-to-existing-project)

Now the issue I am having is converting the tests to use the livedoc-mocha format. For example, the deposit-pool-tests.js file looks like this:

```
export default function() {
contract('RocketDepositPool', async (accounts) => {

    // Accounts
    const [
        owner,
        node,
        trustedNode,
        staker,
        random,
    ] = accounts;

    // Setup
    before(async () => {
        // Register node
        await registerNode({from: node});

        // Register trusted node
        await registerNode({from: trustedNode});
        await setNodeTrusted(trustedNode, 'saas_1', 'node@home.com', owner);
    });

    //
    // Deposit
    //

    it(printTitle('staker', 'can make a deposit'), async () => {
        // Deposit
        await deposit({
            from: staker,
            value: '10'.ether,
        });

        // Get current rETH exchange rate
        let exchangeRate1 = await getRethExchangeRate();

        // Update network ETH total to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate
        let totalBalance = '13'.ether;
        let rethSupply = await getRethTotalSupply();
        await submitBalances(1, totalBalance, 0, rethSupply, {from: trustedNode});

        // Get & check updated rETH exchange rate
        let exchangeRate2 = await getRethExchangeRate();
        assertBN.notEqual(exchangeRate1, exchangeRate2, 'rETH exchange rate has not changed');

        // Deposit again with updated rETH exchange rate
        await deposit({
            from: staker,
            value: '10'.ether,
        });
    });
```

My attempt of doing this with livedoc-mocha looks like this:

```
feature(`Deposit Pool Tests`, () => {
background(`Background steps`, () => {
    given(`Account setup`, async () => {
        contract('RocketDepositPool', async (accounts) => {
                // Accounts
                const [
                    owner,
                    node,
                    trustedNode,
                    staker,
                    random,
                ] = accounts;

            // Register node
            await registerNode({from: node});

            // Register trusted node
            await registerNode({from: trustedNode});
            await setNodeTrusted(trustedNode, 'saas_1', 'node@home.com', owner);
        });
    });
});

    scenario("Staker Can Make a Deposit", () => {
        given("Staker deposits 10 Ether", async () => {
            // Deposit
            await deposit({
                from: staker,
                value: '10'.ether,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This generates the following results:

> Feature: Deposit Pool Tests
> Background: Background steps
> √ Given Account setup (624ms)
> Scenario: Staker Can Make a Deposit
>
> 1. Given Staker deposits 10 Ether
>
>    1 passing (644ms)
>    1 failing
>
>    1. Feature: Deposit Pool Tests
>       Scenario: Staker Can Make a Deposit
>       Given Staker deposits 10 Ether:
>       ReferenceError: staker is not defined

I can't figure out how to wrap the whole feature file in the contract and run the setup steps only once. Background is supposed to run once for each scenario which isn't exactly the behavior I want.

I've also tried to get this to work with mocha-cakes-2. This is my attempted implementation:

```
export default function() {
contract('RocketDepositPool', async (accounts) => {
    Feature('Deposit Pool Tests', () => {

        Scenario('Staker can make a deposit before and after updating the rETH exchange rate', () => { 
          let exchangeRate1;

            // Accounts
            const [
                owner,
                node,
                trustedNode,
                staker,
                random,
            ] = accounts;

                // Setup
            before(async () => {
                // Register node
                await registerNode({from: node});

                // Register trusted node
                await registerNode({from: trustedNode});
                await setNodeTrusted(trustedNode, 'saas_1', 'node@home.com', owner);
            });

          Given('The staker deposits 10 ETH', async () => {
            await deposit({
                from: staker,
                value: '10'.ether,
            });
          });

            When('The rETH exchange rate is retreived', async () => {
                exchangeRate1 = await getRethExchangeRate();
                console.log(exchangeRate1);
            });

            When('The network ETH total is updated to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate', async () => {
                let totalBalance = '13'.ether;
                let rethSupply = await getRethTotalSupply();
                await submitBalances(1, totalBalance, 0, rethSupply, {from: trustedNode});
            });

            And('The rETH exchange rate is checked', async () => {
                let exchangeRate2 = await getRethExchangeRate();
                console.log(exchangeRate1);
                console.log(exchangeRate2);
                assertBN.notEqual(exchangeRate1, exchangeRate2, 'rETH exchange rate has not changed');
            });

            Then('The staker can deposit again with the updated rETH exchange rate', async () => {
                await deposit({
                    from: staker,
                    value: '10'.ether,
                });
            });
          });
    });
});
```

}
And this is the error I'm getting:

```
 Contract: RocketDepositPool
Feature: Deposit Pool Tests
  Scenario: Staker can make a deposit before and after updating the rETH exchange rate
    √ Given The staker deposits 10 ETH (225ms)
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 56885248, 2993385, 222, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 3,
  red: null
}
    √ When The rETH exchange rate is retreived
    √ When The network ETH total is updated to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate (90ms)
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 56885248, 2993385, 222, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 3,
  red: null
}
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 56885248, 2993385, 222, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 3,
  red: null
}
    1) And The rETH exchange rate is checked
    √ Then The staker can deposit again with the updated rETH exchange rate (212ms)

  Gas Usage: (697975 gas)
    Scenario: Staker can make a deposit before and after updating the rETH exchange rate (697975 gas)
      Given The staker deposits 10 ETH (243472 gas)
      When The rETH exchange rate is retreived (0 gas)
  When The network ETH total is updated to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate (211031 gas)
  And The rETH exchange rate is checked (0 gas)
  Then The staker can deposit again with the updated rETH exchange rate (243472 gas)

  4 passing (17s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: RocketDepositPool
   Feature: Deposit Pool Tests
     Scenario: Staker can make a deposit before and after updating the rETH exchange rate
       And The rETH exchange rate is checked:

  rETH exchange rate has not changed
  + expected - actual


  at Object.notEqual (test\_helpers\/bn.js:6:16)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test\deposit\/deposit-pool-tests-mocha-cakes-2.js:68:30)
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Would defining `accounts` at the `feature` level (instead of inside a `given` block) would help? It would then be accessible from all `given` blocks within that feature

Comment: If I just move the array of accounts to the feature block I get the error that accounts are not defined. I think that block has to be after the contract since we're doing a `async (accounts)` in the contract

Comment: As a workaround, would you try and use a combination of `before` and `beforeEach` functions? You could use a `before` function to call the `contract` function and store the `accounts` array, and then a `beforeEach` function to run the setup steps for each account.

Comment: @VonC the `before` and `beforeEach` keywords are part of mocha and not part of livedoc-mocha, so I'm not sure they'll play nice

Comment: I'm starting to think the `mocha-cakes-2` library might be better for what I'm trying to do

Comment: Given that Livedoc-mocha is an extension to Mocha, these functions should work with it... to be tested. That or you manually manage the state and only perform setup steps if they haven't been done yet (Before each scenario, the `background` steps will run, but the `setup` steps inside the `given('Account setup')` block will be skipped if a flag `setupDone` is true).

Comment: `mocha-cakes-2` is indeed another library that enables Gherkin-style syntax (Given/When/Then) in Mocha tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254530/discussion-between-user2007843-and-vonc).